# Solution to bind 2+ arrays as params in MySQL prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, bindparam

I was able to bind 1 array as a parameter no problem. However, I am trying to bind 2+ arrays as parameters and its not going over so well. I keep getting an error that I cannot use positional arguments after unpacking. How do I combine the arrays as parameters?

```
$query="SELECT price FROM products WHERE status='1'";
if(isset($_POST['category'])){
    $category_filter = join(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['category']), '?'));
    $sql .= ' AND category IN ('.$category_filter.')';
}if(isset($_POST['location'])){
    $location_filter = join(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['location']), '?'));
    $sql .= ' AND location IN ('.$location_filter.')';
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('ss', count($_POST['category'],$_POST['location'])), ...$_POST['category'],...$_POST['location']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($price);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to combine the two lists together and then bind them in one go...

```
$params = array_merge($_POST['category'],$_POST['location']);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($params)), ...$params);
```

Comment: wow thanks, you saved me! i know this isnt part of the question, but i hope i may still ask it. If a user deselects all parameters in the filter i get an error saying that it cannot count on 0 and that the parameter is undefined. is there a way i can not bind the parameter if it is null/undefined? id be happy to ask another question if you want to get another accepted answer

Comment: You could add `if ( count($params) > 0)` before the `bind_param()`.